# Flutter, How to remove pan following effect from interactiveviewer

Tags: flutter

From Here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onPanEnd.html

there is velocity concept.

I want to remove after drag by some velocity.

How to remove following moving or make velocity to 0?

I want to very not flexible interactive viewer.

EDIT:

STICKY TRANSFORMCONTROLLER CODE:

```
    class CustomSecondTransformationController extends TransformationController {
      CustomSecondTransformationController([Matrix4? value])
          : super(value ?? Matrix4.identity());
    
    
    
      set before(Offset value) {
        _before = value;
      }
    
      Offset toScene(Offset viewportPoint) {
        Offset vp = viewportPoint;
        final Matrix4 inverseMatrix = Matrix4.inverted(value);
    
        final Vector3 untransformed = inverseMatrix.transform3(Vector3(
          vp.dx,
          vp.dy,
          0,
        ));
    
        return Offset(untransformed.x / 3, untransformed.y / 3);

  }
```

Comment: What do you want to remove after drag by some velocity.?

Comment: @Rohan Thacker  Actually I want to make sticky interactive viewer like my edit.

Comment: @Rohan Thacker And https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer/transformationController.html

I used that examples, but it seems that after drag make my reset animation very uncomfortable.. so that I want to remove after drag.

Comment: I have the same request to remove inertia of InteractiveViewer, in order to get the exact offset of the child after pan for drawing scrollbar by my self. I'm trying to copy and modify InteractiveViewer's source.

Comment: Would like to remove the inertia, too. Is there a solution? (The sticky transformation controller given above still allows inertia to work.)

Comment: Having the same problem. I made a function that works well limiting the pan inside the onInteractionUpdate, but it complety fails in the end callback (onInteractionEnd). It seems that velocity is applied after my funcion, to translate the image, leaving my pan in a positioned that I wanted to limit!

Answer (score 0):

Even if the question is pretty old, I still stumbled on this while trying to make a cropping tool, and found some potential solutions.

**Technique 1 - decreasing kDrag to a very low value**

This pretty much the best in terms of stopping follow animation, it might have some small followup, but pretty much invisible. Also there is no need to create a stateful widget for implementing this

```dart
final kDrag = 1e-200;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return InteractiveViewer(
     interactionEndFrictionCoefficient: kDrag,
     //...
  );
}
```

**Technique 2 - snapping to the last interaction end location**

This is more involved and also aggressive to the eye, and will snap the user to the point where they stopped interacting.

```
TransformationController _controller = TransformationController();
ScaleStartDetails _start;
ScaleUpdateDetails _update;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return InteractiveViewer(
    controller: _controller,
    onInteractionStart: (start) {
      _start = start;
    }
    onInteractionUpdate: (update) {
      _update = update;
    },
    onInteractionEnd: (_) {
      if (_start == null || _update == null){
        return;
      }
    
      final dx = _update.localFocalPoint.dx - _start.localFocalPoint.dx;
      final dy = _update.localFocalPoint.dy - _start.localFocalPoint.dy;
    
      // here you might need setState depending on the setup widget
      _controller.value = Matrix4.indentity()..translate(dx, dy);
    }
     //...
  );
}
```